# Why is the click event on a hyperlink not being triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Why is the click event on a hyperlink not fired?

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Show the privacy policy", 
    "PrivacyPolicy", 
    null, 
    new { id = "privacyLink" })

<div id="privacy"></div> 

<script> 
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // $('div').addClass('fooh');
        $('div#myDiv').click(function () {
            alert('div was clicked');
        });
        $('a#privacyLink').click(function () {
            alert('a');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The `myDiv` click event is fired as expected but the `privacyLink`'s event is not fired, that is the alert is not shown.

**Generated HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/AjaxDemo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>
            <div id="title">
                <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="logindisplay">
                    [ <a href="/Account/LogOn">Log On</a> ]

            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="main">
            <h2>Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!</h2>
<p>
    To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
</p>
<div id="myDiv">
<p>
Me Gusta
</p>
</div>




<a href="/Home/PrivacyPolicy" id="privacyLink">Show the privacy policy</a>


<div id="privacy"></div> 



<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // $('div').addClass('fooh');
        $('div#myDiv').click(function () {

            alert('div was clicked');
        });

        $('a#privacyLink').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('a');
            $(location).src = $(this).attr('href');
        });

    });



</script>
        </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you click on the link?

Comment: just redirects to the specified action

Comment: There are a couple of possibilities that come to mind: you have more than one element with `id="privacyLink"` in your DOM or you have some javascript error preventing the click handler to be attached (look at your js console for that).

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I checked it thoroughly but failed to find an error :(

Comment: Could you post the generated HTML as seen by browsing the source from the browser? This might help in understading the problem as we would have the full markup allowing to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I have added it to the question, please check it.

Comment: What's inside the `AjaxDemo.js` script?

Comment: the html u posted - if i ignore your AJAX script and modernizr-1.7.min.js - the <a> click works fine

Comment: @DarinDimitrov same script just tried to see if it works if I include it as an external file

Comment: Yeah, but in this case you should remove it from your inline HTML to avoid having it in two different places.

Comment: It works fine for me too. I pasted the html between the body tags and the javascript in the script tag in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jCWPk/). Of course it does not include those other js files.

Comment: @user1428716 it works now, but since I have been working with the internet template I never removed the modernizr-1.7.min.js file but I was always done

Answer (score 3):

Other than the fact that you should return false from the click callback of your anchor to prevent the browser from redirecting away I do not see anything wrong with it:

```
$('a#privacyLink').click(function () {
    alert('a');
    return false;
});
```

Also make sure that you do not have other elements with `id="privacyLink"` anywhere in your DOM because ids must be unique.

Also check your js console in the browser to ensure that you do not have some javascript errors preventing the .click handler to be attached properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this : 
Since your anchor is not formed , your binding is not working. Use http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
  $("a#privacyLink").on("click", function(event){
     alert('a');
  });
```

This is the jsfiddle to simulate your condition (Dynamic generation of HTML elements)

```
  http://jsfiddle.net/nhNpw/6/
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Since your anchor is not formed`? The anchor is right there in his markup.

Comment: I dont know about ASP . but seems like he is creating it Dynamically on the client side

Comment: This is no different than what he currently has.

Comment: The anchor is created on the server side using the Html.ActionLink helper. If this was for example code from a partial view loaded with AJAX then your answer would have been correct. But this doesn't explain why the click on the div works.

Comment: If the problem was that the anchor doesn't yet exist at the time of binding, then this still wouldn't help. It would need to be something like `$(document.body).on('click', '#privacyLink', function() { alert('a'); });`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with event `preventDefault()` method.

```
$('a#privacyLink').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('a');
  $(location).attr('href', $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud Do you have alert with `$('a').click(...`?